# jQuery - trigger not produce the expected result

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my app, while page load i initiate my `init` function for 3 things,

1. trigger and sending a page no. (i would like to pass page default as 1)
2. when trigger done, i want to hear that so i am listening
3. again, a user can insert / edit the page number (text box) so i am adding a listener to function.

but when function start i am consoling a object but i am getting result as `undifined`.

what is wrong here:

```
var docLoader = function (params) {

    window.container = window.container || $("#tenderContent");

    return {
        init : function () {
            this.cachePages = {};
            $(document).on("newMessage", this.onPageChange);
            $.event.trigger({
                type: "newMessage"
            });
        },

        onPageChange : function (e) {
            console.log(this.cachePages) //undefined why?
        }
    }
}
```

html page :

```
<script>
    docLoader().init();
</script>
```

I am new to de-coupled approach any one help me with details please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you lose the `this` context. jQuery passes the DOM element as the context, not whatever the original context was.

You need to bind the context of the function to your existing `this`:

```
$(document).on("newMessage", this.onPageChange.bind(this));
```